# Is it possible to filter within a windowing function's partition

Tags: sql, t-sql

Here is a table I created to explain what I want to do:

```
create table #test (
    PlaceID int, 
    ItemID int, 
    ItemCount int, 
    Amount dec(11,2)
)
```

I would like to get 3 things:

1. sum by Place
2. sum by Place and Item
3. sum by Place and Non-item

The first two are simple:

```
sum(Amount) over (partition by PlaceID) as PlaceAmount
sum(Amount) over (partition by PlaceID, ItemID) as PlaceItemAmount
```

But how do I get the sum for all items in the place that are NOT the current item?

Here is a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/297ad/1) with the data and query set up:

Comment: What is your definition of Non-item?

Comment: Based on your fiddle, what do you expect this third sum to be?

Comment: @Blam - All ItemIDs that are not the ItemID of the current row.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server do you use?

Comment: @JesanFafon - Good question and possibly the answer to my question... I'm expecting PlaceAmount - Amount...

Comment: @HamletHakobyan - target is 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t1.PlaceID, t1.ItemID, t1.ItemCount
     , t1.Amount as 'AmtMe'
     , SumPlace.sum as 'AmtPlace' 
     , SumPlace.sum - t1.Amount as 'AmtPlaceNoMe'
  from #test as t1
  join (select PlaceID, sum(Amount) as 'sum'
          from #test 
         group by PlaceID) as SumPlace 
    on t1.PlaceID = SumPlace.PlaceID
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you were expecting? Basically, take your whole (partition by place) and subtract your current (partition by place, item) to get the remainder. I would, however, mention that keeping this in a subquery so as to only run the windowed aggregates once per function and partition set.

Same can go for counts, using that logic as well.

```
select
    PlaceID,
    ItemID,
    ItemCount,
    Amount,
    PlaceItemCount,
    PlaceAmount,
    ItemAndPlaceAmount,
    PlaceAmount-ItemAndPlaceAmount as RemainderAmount
from (
  select
      PlaceID,
      ItemID,
      ItemCount,
      Amount,
      sum(ItemCount) over (partition by PlaceID) as PlaceItemCount,
      sum(Amount) over (partition by PlaceID) as PlaceAmount,
      sum(Amount) over (partition by PlaceID, ItemID) as ItemAndPlaceAmount
  from tblTest
  ) z
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    PlaceID,
    ItemID,
    ItemCount,
    Amount,
    sum(ItemCount) over (partition BY PlaceID) AS PlaceItemCount,
    sum(Amount) over (partition BY PlaceID) AS PlaceAmount
  , sum(Amount) over (partition BY PlaceID, ItemID) AS PlaceItemAmount
  , sum(Amount) over (partition BY PlaceID)
  - sum(Amount) over (partition BY PlaceID, ItemID) AS PlaceItemAmountMinusGroup
  , sum(Amount) over (partition BY PlaceID) - Amount PlaceItemAmountMinusThis
FROM tblTest
```

`PlaceItemAmountMinusGroup` is the total amount by place without the total amount of `ItemID`
`PlaceItemAmountMinusThis` is the total amount by place without the amount of the row.

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/297ad/2)